# Put request using rest

Tags: java, rest, restlet

I have recently begun studyin the restlet interface. I don t know how to translate this method put using the restlet interface.

```
curl -X PUT  http://ip:port/testdb2
```

How can I translate this request? 
So far , i have this code :

```
  ClientResource resource = new ClientResource("http://"+this.ip+":5984/"); 


        // Send the HTTP GET request 
        Representation r=resource.get(); 

        if (resource.getStatus().isSuccess()) { 
           resource.getResponseEntity().write(System.out); 
        }   

        resource.put(null);

        if (resource.getStatus().isSuccess()){ 
             resource.getResponseEntity().write(System.out); 
        } else 
            System.out.println("Error put");
```

How do I specify the new url?
I need this request to create a couchDB database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rephrasing your question, I'll use "How do I issue a PUT request to this url ..."

Per http://www.restlet.org/documentation/2.0/firstResource#part07

Perhaps something like

```
ClientResource dbResource = new ClientResource(  
            "http://"+this.ip+":5984/testdb2");

Representation r = dbResource.put(null);
```

Comment: I don't think we have to open a new connection each time we have to make a request.